How to change format of a Date column and keep it a date column
I hope this question isn't duplicated but I really can't find the answer.
I have a Date class column in format yyyy-mm-dd. I need to export this column to excel in a dd-mm-yyyy column but still as a Date class column.
Every option I have tried, converts the Date class column to a character class after managing to change the format.
This is some example data:
structure(c(18793, 18802, 18802, 18795, 18810, 18789, 18802, 
18807, 18802, 18817, 18788, 18790, 18796, 18810, 18779, 18800, 
18783, 18791, 18808, 18806, 18802, 18808, 18800, 18801, 18860, 
18812, 18812, 18812, 18808, 18793, 18810, 18789, 18792, 18800, 
18789, 18805, 18800, 18792, 18816, 18807, 18804, 18787, 18795, 
18793, 18815, 18795, 18833, 18798, 18807, 18805), class = "Date")

I hope you can help!

I think we also need to know how you are exporting to excel, as there may be some type coercion occurring.

AFAIK this is not possible, the date class only accepts date in the format yyyy-mm-dd. Any other will be transformed to character (at least using format)

@PGSA,i am exporting using write.xlsx

From the notes on write.xlsx: The default formats for Date and DateTime columns can be changed via the two package options xlsx.date.format and xlsx.datetime.format. It's probably worth experimenting with those.

Try this: format(df, "%d-%m-%Y")
df = tibble(
  as_date = df, 
  as_char = format(df, "%d-%m-%Y"))

> df
# A tibble: 50 × 2
   as_date    as_char   
   <date>     <chr>     
 1 2021-06-15 15-06-2021
 2 2021-06-24 24-06-2021
 3 2021-06-24 24-06-2021
 4 2021-06-17 17-06-2021
 5 2021-07-02 02-07-2021
 6 2021-06-11 11-06-2021
 7 2021-06-24 24-06-2021
 8 2021-06-29 29-06-2021
 9 2021-06-24 24-06-2021
10 2021-07-09 09-07-2021

#
write_xlsx(df, "temp.xlsx")

The MS Excel output:

# Toy data
df <- structure(
  c(18793, 18802, 18802, 18795, 18810, 18789, 18802, 18807, 18802, 18817, 
    18788, 18790, 18796, 18810, 18779, 18800, 18783, 18791, 18808, 18806, 
    18802, 18808, 18800, 18801, 18860, 18812, 18812, 18812, 18808, 18793, 
    18810, 18789, 18792, 18800, 18789, 18805, 18800, 18792, 18816, 18807, 
    18804, 18787, 18795, 18793, 18815, 18795, 18833, 18798, 18807, 18805), 
  
  class = "Date")

